# User defined literal for std::integral_constant

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, constant-expression

I created a user defined literal `_c` to convert an "integer" literal into an [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant). Basically, the goal is to allow users to write `std::integral_constant` instances without the usual boilerplate. Here is the implementation:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto pow_helper(T acc, T value, U times)
    -> T
{
    return (times > 1) ?
        pow_helper(acc*value, value, times-1) :
            acc;
}

// Compile-time pow function, only works with
// an unsigned integer exponent
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto pow(T value, U exponent)
    -> T
{
    return (exponent == 0) ? 1 :
        (exponent > 0) ? pow_helper(value, value, exponent) :
            1 / pow_helper(value, value, -exponent);
}

// Structure to parse an integer literal
template<typename Integral, char C, char... Digits>
struct parse
{
    static constexpr Integral value =
        parse<Integral, C>::value * pow(10u, sizeof...(Digits))
        + parse<Integral, Digits...>::value;
};

// Specialization of parse to parse a single
// decimal digit
template<typename Integral, char C>
struct parse<Integral, C>
{
    static_assert(C >= '0' && C <= '9',
                  "only characters in range 0..9 are accepted");

    static constexpr Integral value = C - '0';
};

// User defined literal for std::integral_constant
template<char... Digits>
constexpr auto operator"" _c()
    -> std::integral_constant<int, parse<int, Digits...>::value>
{
    return {};
}
```

With this literal, wirting `42_c` generates an instance of `std::integral_constant<int, 42>`. Here is a small working example:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << 45_c << '\n';   // prints 45
    std::cout << -23_c << '\n';  // prints -23

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(58_c), std::integral_constant<int, 58>>::value, "");
}
```

To generate other integral constants, I plan to add the user defined literals `_cl`, `_cll`, `_cu`, `_cul` and `_cull` whoe implementation is exactly the same, only the resulting type differs.

Is there a way to improve this code and/or make it cleaner or more idiomatic? Have I missed some potential flaws?

Comment: Maybe it would be more idiomatic if the type of the literal adjusted to the size of the number, just like for ordinary integer literals. The whole idea can also be simplified by using `lit<45>` with alias templates, or by multiplying on the fly (sketch: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cca450bf7c1e866)

Comment: [Jeremy W. Murphy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/413597/jeremy-w-murphy) once suggested exponentiation by squaring: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16443849/420683 Not sure why you require `exponent` to be unsigned but then treat the case `exponent < 0`..

Comment: @dyp Exponentiation by squaring indeed sounds good. Concerning the strange check, you are totally right: I actually pulled the `pow` function from an old project and the template parameter names were irrelevant. I thought that the function couldn't handle negative values and din't read the code again. You're totally right.

Comment: @dyp your first "on the fly" sketch is cool! Exponentiation by squaring is not really needed to speed up anything, because `parse` still needs a loop though all values. In a simpler loop, your `value` gets the whole job done, no exponentiation needed.

Comment: @dyp And the way it handles negative exponents is broken anyway, I forgot a minus sign. I will a least add that since there are still no reviews (*working code they said*).

Comment: @dyp By the way, in [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16443849/1364752), the exponentiation by squaring algorithm seems different than the one described in the Wikipedia article, is this normal?

Comment: There's no particular reason why it's different. I immediately knew what Jeremy was referring to, so I implemented it off the top of my head, IIRC. Well I've changed it now to match the algorithm shown at Wikipedia, probably reduces the number of recursions but not much I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Usage of "fat" templates

I would try to avoid using full-blown class templates when there's an elegant alternative solution with alias templates or `constexpr` functions. Note that I didn't measure this, so take it with a grain of salt: lightweight constexpr functions and alias template can be faster to instantiate. Using `constexpr` functions might reduce the number of instantiations to a minimum of 1 (the literal operator template) or two (the constexpr function template with a single template type parameter).

#### Algorithm

By changing the order of operations, you can get rid of the `pow` function (template) entirely: Pass the current result to the next step, then multiply and add. The shifting (in base 10) will be done on the fly.

Sketch:

```
constexpr int combine(int p)
{
    return p;
}

template<class... TT>
constexpr int combine(int val, int p0, TT... pp)
{
    return combine(val*10 + p0, pp...);
}

constexpr int parse(char C)
{
    return (C >= '0' && C <= '9')
           ? C - '0'
           : throw std::out_of_range("only decimal digits are allowed");
}

template<char... Digits>
constexpr auto operator"" _c()
-> std::integral_constant<int, combine(0, parse(Digits)...)>
{
    return {};
}
```

#### Literals in other bases

Your parse function currently rejects hexadecimal, octal, and in C++1y binary literals, as well as C++1y's digit separators. Supporting the bases < 10 is fairly simple because you only need to change the "shifting" factor. I.e. multiply by 8 or 2 instead of 10. For base 16, you also need to add some code to the character -> digit conversion. IIRC, it's not guaranteed that the letters are contiguous in the basic execution character set (as opposed to the digits), so this could be rather painful w/o a switch or lookup-table. Also, upper/lower case.

#### Automatically growing literal type

Normal C++ literals automatically adjust their types according to their value. If they don't fit into an `int`, they'll try `long`, `long long` etc. Maybe one of the user-defined literals should mimic that behaviour for convenience.

#### Operators

Unfortunately, the StdLib doesn't provide operators for `std::integral_constant`. Therefore, `-23_c` will not be a `std::integral_constant<int, -23>` but rather an `int` (via the implicit conversion operator). I find that surprising.

Consider using a custom type, possibly derived from / convertible to `std::integral_constant` and provide (metaprogramming) operators for this type.

---

Side remark:

`lit<45>` is much easier to implement:

```
template<std::uintmax_t N>
using lit = std::integral_constant<std::uintmax_t, N>;
```

Comment: The class I wrote with this idea in mind has indeed custom operators. I agree that `lit<N>` is easier to implement, but I wanted the UDL syntax to work. I think that I will use some (most) of your ideas to improve the overall design. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Morwenn Oh, btw. I think it'll currently do the wrong thing for octal literals. So maybe you want at least to detect those.

Comment: You're right. I don't intend to implement the literals thing (too much work, and my class is math-related, so I expect people to use decimal literals), but warning about the octals literals is definitely a good idea :)

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation. For anyone who comes across this looking for a slightly more complete solution, here's an implementation that supports hex, octal, and binary literals, along with the digit separator: https://gist.github.com/mattbierner/5c698972de0cdd9de86a

Comment: @MattBierner Your code does assume that `'A'` through `'F'` are represented by consecutive numbers, though..

Comment: @MattBierner Also, `integral_constant` is IMHO not a good choice for the return type, because of the operator issue I've mentioned in my answer.